# Disable "Close Window" on the taskbar for Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

How to make inactive the *"Close Window"* on the taskbar?

[image]

The [`AllowCancelDuringInstall`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_allowcancelduringinstall) blocks the taskbar only during installation, but I need it to be blocked always.

Comment: What? That's the Inno Setup Compiler. You can't modify that. Are you trying to disable the close button for your own setup? If so, why? If the user wants to cancel setup, let them. Pretty sure there's a "Cancel" button on the dialog, too.

Comment: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_allowcancelduringinstall
Here it blocks the taskbar only during installation, but I need to always have.

Comment: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_allowcancelduringinstall

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable the *"Close window"* command. Neither the `AllowCancelDuringInstall` disables the command, it just makes the command non-functional.

To make the command non-functional during whole setup run, just disable the *Cancel* button on every page:

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  WizardForm.CancelButton.Enabled := False;
end;
```

Though I do not see any point of doing that. There's no way you can prevent the user from aborting the installer by going to *Task Manager* anyway.

Comment: There's no way to have the *Cancel* button working but *Close window* not working. What sense that it make anyway? What are you trying to do?

Comment: All you can do is to implement a new *Cancel* button on your own and hide the standard one.

Comment: You had yourself given the `AllowCancelDuringInstall` as an example of what you are trying to do. And this directive disables the *Cancel* button.

Comment: *Here at this stage of the installation is that the screenshot should be inactive* - What does that mean? When you can to inactivate these? Only on the *Select destination location*, but not before?

Comment: Cancel button must be active on all components except : InstallingPage!

Comment: That is, during installation, it must not active !

Comment: So *Cancel* button should behave as with `AllowCancelDuringInstall`, but *Close window* command must be non-functional always? Why?

Comment: To not be just close the window !

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by *"To not be just close the window !"*.

Comment: that prevent the closure of the program

Comment: But that's what the *Cancel* button does too. The *Close window* command does the same what the *Cancel* button does. So why do you want them to behave differently?

Comment: It is necessary that the program is set to end , and that the user is not able to stop her !

Comment: I explained everything I could !

Comment: But you want the *Cancel* button to be enabled, so the user can use the button to cancel the installation. I'm lost, sorry.

Comment: You can close the taskbar , and the rest work as I need ! Not sure of the correctness of the code !

Comment: *"You can close the taskbar"* - I assume you mean *"You can close setup from the taskbar"*. - Again, sure you can, as long as the *Cancel* button is enabled. We are spinning in circles. I do not understand why you want to prevent user from using *"Close window"*, but allow him to use *"Cancel"* button. I'm giving up. You may have more luck explaining your problem at [Stack Overflow на русском](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/).